# Swift - Passing a parameter to a web service

Tags: swift, web-services, web, soap

I've come to a brick wall with this.Can anyone help? I have a web service that requires a parameter called FilteredString which has to be passed to a web service called GetProjectRegisterFiltered. I've tried a number of variations but I still get no results back. The web service is identical to another that works, I've just added a parameter to it.

```
    func GetFilteredRecords(){
    let is_SoapMessage: String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    let URL: String = "http://192.168.1.208:8080/Service.asmx"
    let WebRequ = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL)! as URL)
    WebRequ.httpMethod = "POST"
    WebRequ.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    WebRequ.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    WebRequ.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    WebRequ.addValue("myServices/GetProjectRegisterFiltered", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    var Str: String = ""
    let task = session.dataTask(with: WebRequ as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        Str = String(strData!) as String
        print(strData!)
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&lt;", with: "<")
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&gt;", with: ">")
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&amp;", with: "&")
        let data2 = Data(Str.utf8)
        self.ReadPRData(Data: data2)

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: " + error.debugDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Not related: Avoid `NSStuff` when available: `NSMutableURLRequest` => `URLRequest`, `NSURL` => `URL`, that should avoid you the `as URLRequest`, etc. Avoid naming your variable starting with an upper case, and fully name them: `let WebRequ` => `let webRequest` or `let request`. Your method too: `ReadPRData(Data: data2)` `readPRData(data: data2)` (might want to remove the double "data"). Finally, you should use a `[weak self]` here for memory leak issue.

Comment: `WebRequ.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")` is strange. Isn't `is_SoapMessage` already a String? Did you meant `String(is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))` instead? Also, does `GetProjectRegisterFiltered` really need to be put inside the header, or should it be in `is_SoapMessage`, send through the `httpBody`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Swift and I've played around with the code that many times and tried that many variations I've forgotten where I'm up to. Avoiding the NSStuff is a welcome tip. I noticed that Swift complains about that quite a bit. I thought all I would need to do is add a single line like    WebRequ.addValue("My Param", forHTTPHeaderField: "FilteredString")  but no such luck :(

Comment: Also, the WSDL Web Services were created on a windows machine using VB.NET and Visual Studio. Not sure if that matters. I've used Web Services for years using VB.NET and C# without issues, but now I'm dabbling in Swift it's a big learning curve :)

Comment: A tip since you seem to be experimented in other languages in that domain. You could try to reproduce your request in POSTMAN, and it can generate Swift code that could inspire you on where to put the elements (header, body, etc.) It's not always very good looking code, but to know if we need to put it in header, url, or body is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to thank everyone for their replies. I didn't have a full understanding of how SOAP requests work. I do now though. I wasn't aware that I just needed to add the variables to the SOAP request string like so:

```
is_SoapMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetDiaryByDay xmlns=\"MyWebWebsite\"><Username>\(Username)</Username><Password>\(Password)</Password><Day>\(Day)</Day><Month>\(Month)</Month><Year>\(Year)</Year></GetDiaryByDay></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```